# Emptying contents of a list

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a list as such

```
std::list<foo*> lst;
```

If I do the following:

```
lst.clear
```

will that call the destructor of all items in the list ? or will I have to call the destructor individually for each item ? If not what would be the best way to empty the contents of the list and have the destructor of the pointers called  ? Will the following work or is there a better way to do it

```
 for(
     std::list<foo*>::iterator listMyClassIter = lst.begin();
     listMyClassIter != lst.end();
     listMyClassIter ++) {
     delete listMyClassIter;   }

 lst.clear(); //Now clear the content
```

Comment: Some questions: what do the pointers point to? What is the lifetime of those objects? Who owns them, if anyone?

Comment: Your `for` loop does the right thing.  However, if you need this at more than one point, your code will quickly become spaghetti like.  To mitigate this issue, at the very least, wrap that logic into an object that is responsible for managing the lifetime of the objects the `vector`'s elements are pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is of pointers and pointers don't have destructors. That means you have to explicitly delete pointers in the container.

EDITED AS QUESTION IS EDITED:-

If you want your list to automatically manage memory for you then you can use boost::shared_ptr rather than storing raw pointers.

You can do either of following on raw pointers:-

```
for (...) { delete *it; } m_list.clear ();
```

OR

```
for (...) { delete *it; m_ilist.erase (); }
```

Comment: But maybe you don't. Not all pointers need to have `delete` called on them.

Comment: As of fall 2014, we also have C++11 with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` ready.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using pointer as element, destructor won't be called.